# How to store periodicity in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Which column type should be used to store a periodicity in Oracle?

- *Daily*: time, e. g. "14:00"
- *Weekly*: day of week, time, e. g. "Mon 14:00"
- *Monthly*: day of month, time, e. g. "24 14:00"
- *Yearly*: month, day, time, e. g. "12-24 14:00"
- *Week of year*: calendar week, day, time, e. g. "W01 Mon 14:00"

Especially because of the calendar week I guess storing a pattern as text in [ISO 8601 format](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) could work. Or is there a better solution that works e. g. on timestamps?

The intent is only to store a pattern in the database. This pattern will then be used to create a periodicity for dates in a given time interval.

Example using Jodatime in Java:

```
Start DateTime: 2017-01-01
End DateTime: 2017-01-03
Periodicity: Daily, 02:00 - 06:00 
(this is what my question is about, i. e. how to store it)
```

In Java the following intervals will be created using these data, the created intervals will not be stored in the database, they'll be only processed:

```
2017-01-01 02:00 - 2017-01-01 06:00
2017-01-02 02:00 - 2017-01-02 06:00
```

Comment: An interesting question. How will this values be used? Which queries will be issued?

Comment: They'll be used in Java to create a list of intervals. No query, Oracle can't handle that as far as I know. But if it can, it'd be great.

Comment: @Roland   It's impossible to get data out of oracle without a query, do that answer does not make sense.  Perhaps you can elaborate more on how these will be used.

Comment: VARCHAR2 could be an option, but you shoud consider to use the Oracle  [Calendaring Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF) - depending on your needs. With [DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF) you can even evaluate the string.

Comment: @GurV The question is, what is the advantage of using DATE columns in contrast to strings using ISO notation as the OP proposes. Some disadvantages come into my mind when using the DATE type: 1.) the representation of a value is not unique, e. "Mo, 14:30" can be represented by a lot of  DATEs. So you can't easily establish unique contraint, check equality ... 2) Some work may be necessary to find e reprenentative. Which day can be  used to represent "W01 Mon 14:00"? But what is the advantage of date?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  maybe to Oracle specific.but it  looks interesting

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you, apparently Oracle themselves save that information / pattern as `VARCHAR2`